# Bash Script to rename file inside a directory

Tags: bash, rename

I have a file named `syscheck.sh` in `/system/0211/` and I want to rename it to `checkone.sh`.

How can I do it?

Comment: I removed the unnecessary information to just go to the specific point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do a rename in a bash script, you simply need to use the `mv` (move) command.

```
mv /system/0211/syscheck.sh /system/0211/checkone.sh
```

You can put this command inside a shell script `myrenamescript.sh` file like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
mv /system/0211/syscheck.sh /system/0211/checkone.sh
```

Now set the script as executable

```
chmod a+x myrenamescript.sh
```

Now you can run it:

```
./myrenamescript.sh
```